# Write tilde on windows with alt+4

Tags: keyboard

I'm using a spanish keyboard. Usually in Linux when I type `alt + 4` I get `~` but in Windows I also have to press space for the `~` to appear. Is there any way of making windows write `~` just by pressing `alt+4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the free key-remapping product
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

Here is a script for converting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> to `~`,
which works for the `4` key on both the numpad and the non-numpad keys.

```
Alt & 4::Send {ASC 126}
Alt & numpad4::Send {ASC 126}
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.